# Angular & ionic - scrolling issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an app with `angular` and `ionic`, and I am facing a strange issue with scrolling.

What I currently have, is a directive to display some temperatures on a page.
Everything works, but if I try to scroll using the mouse wheel (when the mouse cursor hover some text) the page won't scroll. If, however, I have the mouse cursor somewhere else, the page scrolls.

To better explain and show this issue, I've created a `codepen` which you can find here: http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/beBGdx

I have no idea why this happens.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, same behaviour. I had this reported as a bug by several customers. Obviuosly, on a device, it does that if you start the scroll with your finger on the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround.
Set overflow-scroll="true" in the ion-content.

Comment: It seem to work. Thanks for now, I am going to test it a bit more and extensively :)